# How to give puzzle like effect to the image inside the video using FFMEPG

Tags: ffmpeg, transitions

I want to add an image want to animate an image just like this: https://streamable.com/qvqed.

Input video is this: https://streamable.com/y68e0

How would I achieve this?

Comment: This will be very cumbersome to carry out. Each unique anim will have to be manually constructed. Consider using the [remap](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#remap) [filter](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/RemapFilter).

Comment: @Gyan thanks I will take a look over it. If any question I will ask again :)